# Azure Traffic Manager and OAuth 2.0

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-traffic-manager

We are using Azure Active Directory for registering client applications. 
The client applications use the AAD clientId and secret to get an access token to authenticate to the back end microservices we have in place in Azure.

We have these microservices sitting behind an Azure Traffic Manager. My question is, what will happen to the OAuth 2.0 token if the following scenario occurs:

- A User is authenticated and is using backend microservice 1 (instance 1)
- The user is switched by the traffic manager to backend microservice 1 (instance 2)

Will they need to re-logon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Traffic Manager operates at the DNS level which means that once the service gives an endpoint back to the DNS resolver (in response to a DNS query that was sent by that resolver), it is no longer in the loop and any communication is between the client and the server. Since Azure Traffic Manager is agnostic to what happens between the client and the servers, any application specific token handoffs and switch backs will not be controlled by Traffic Manager

Please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-how-traffic-manager-works/#how-clients-connect-using-traffic-manager for more details