# How does APIM work with Azure traffic manager?

Tags: azure-traffic-manager, ibm-api-management

In APIM we need to have a key that a client knows about: 
ocp-apim-subscription-key

What happens when traffic manager round robins to another server? Does the client need to know about the second subscription key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to [Azure Traffic Manager and OAuth 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986810/azure-traffic-manager-and-oauth-2-0/39172082#39172082) , since Azure Traffic Manager operates at the DNS level, it is not a part of the client-server communication. Any authentication and key handoffs are transparent to Traffic Manager.

Please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-how-traffic-manager-works/#how-clients-connect-using-traffic-manager for more details

Comment: Thanks @dilip l. Can you let me know where I can find the Microsoft documentation for this. I just want to read it for myself. I have been searching but can't find an actual post from Microsoft on it.